# Explain why $F(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x-4}}$ and $G(x)=\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x-4}}$ are not the same.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Explain why $F(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x-4}}$ and $G(x)=\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x-4}}$ are not the same.

The explanation that my friend given,

> Domain of $F$ is $x>4$ and $x>-1$ which becomes $x>4$ whereas Domain for $G$ is $\frac{x+1}{x-4}\geq0$ which becomes $x>4$ or $x\leq -1$.

Is his explanation correct? Why? I would like to know other explanation too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why aren't you content with the given explanation? What happens if you plug in $x=-5$ into either function? Do you see how $G(x)$ allows for the numerator and denominator inside the square root to be simultaneously negative?

Comment: As a simpler example: Could you explain why $\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$ and $x+1$ are not the same?

Comment: Simple exercise:  for which function is  x= -2 defined?  Can you see the different domains of $f(x), g(x)$. In fact, the domain of $f(x)$ is a proper subset of the domain of $g(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

The domain of $F$ is $(4,\infty)$ because it must be the case that both expressions are non-negative. Furthermore it cannot be the case that $x=4$ since one cannot divide by $0$.

In the second case with $G$ the rational expression $\dfrac{x+1}{x-4}$ must be non-negative. The expression is positive for $x>4$, negative in the interval $(-1,4)$ and positive on the interval $(-\infty,-1)$. It is undefined at $x=4$ and $0$ at $x=-1$. Therefore it is non-negative if and only if $x$ is in the set $(-\infty,-1]\cup(4,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

Because the first is real valued iff $x+1$ and $x-4$ are both positive (and $x-4 \ne 0$), the second is real valued if $x+1$ and $x-4$ ($x-4 \ne 0$) have the same sign (positive or negative).

So your result is correct!

Comment: the requirement that $x+1,\;x-4$ are both positive in the "first", rules out your first  parenthesized edit "and $x-4 \neq 0$.  That's redundant.  $x-4 \gt 0$ already rules out x= 0$,  Any way, what I pointed out is irrelevant to the veracity of your answer,

Comment: I agree, but someone consider $0$ in the positive numbers.